# translating certain to the logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

In the question it says every meal  is cooked by a certain chef . I wonder what the certain means in this sentence should i think it is equal meaning with exactly or some

Comment: Good question... The sentence is ambiguous; for sure: "for every meal there is at least one chef that cooks it" is true.  We may have more than one chef to cook a meal ? Maybe.

Answer (score 1):

There is no certain answer to this question . However if You leave out the word "certain" from your sentence it would almost always deny that their must be one chef . So putting the word "certain" in your sentence would tend to mean that there was only one chef . Hope that helps .

Comment: That would be my interpretation and reasoning for it as well!